# Blog is showing code and not page

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates

hii I am novice to python and django. I am referring one tutorial to develop a blog in django.

I have synchronized the database and have run the server.
My admin page is working fine but my application page is showing some problem

I have created an html file "blog.html"

```
(% extends "base.html" %)
(% block content %)

(% for post in object_list %)

<h3>{{ post.title}}</h3>
<div class="post_meta">
on {{post.date}}
</div>
<div class= "post_body">
{{post.body|safe|linebreaks}}
</div>



(%endfor %)
(%endblock %)
```

When i run my django, it is showing this code inspite of actual blog page..

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow and which path is this template file located?

Comment: Django Tutorial Part 4: URL Handling - Web Development and my template is in "C:\Users\K\Desktop\Django\mysite\blog\templates"

Comment: and in cmd it is showing "Get /BLOG/ http/1.1" 200 207

Answer (score 0):

[Django's template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) uses `{%` and `%}` for template tags, not `(%` and `%)` as in your template file.